# How to set PHP_IDE_CONFIG while debugging PHP CLI using PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I've configured Xdebug and PhpStorm properly, and have used Browser Debugging Extensions and successfully tested a PHP CLI server [LaravelFly](https://github.com/scil/LaravelFly) which speeds up Laravel.

```
sudo php /vagrant/www/zc/vendor/scil/laravel-fly/bin/fly start
```

But I failed to test it using PHPUnit today:

```
 sudo php -dxdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.108 vendor/bin/phpunit --stop-on-failure
```

[image]

I added this to Vagrant Ubuntu .zshrc

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=zc.test"
```

but it still does not work and PhpStorm response the same error messag.

Answer (score 1):

In the picture above, I found that $_SERVER['PATH'] is not same with the $PATH of my vagrant user, then I got it.

I removded sudo

```
php -dxdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.108 vendor/bin/phpunit --stop-on-failure
```

Now it works!